# If i add places by my app

Tags: google-maps

My app needs show some places by add javascript.
I read the places api just now,but i had a confusion: if i add many places by my server,can other people see it on my app immediately?and How did google charge for it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have your API KEY people will see the changes immediately.

about the charges for use;

The Google Places API Web Service enforces a default limit of 1,000 free requests per 24 hour period, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side requests. If your app exceeds the initial limit, the app will start failing. You can increase this limit free of charge, up to 150,000 requests per 24 hour period.

The maximum limit for free usage is 150,000 requests per 24 hour period. If your app exceeds the limit, the app will start failing again. Purchase a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan license to get more than 150,000 requests per 24 hour period.

and more you can read from [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage).